# How to delete objects from a list using logical object

Tags: r

I ve a list `list` which has the following structure

```
List of 3
 $ style     : chr "S"
 $ neighbours:List of 1024
  ..$ : int [1:8] 2 3 5 10 11 18 672 673 
 $ weights   :List of 1024
  ..$ : num [1:8] 0.1283 0.1336 0.1026 0.0927 0.071 ...
```

and I have a locical list `test1` with the structure `logi [1:1024] TRUE TRUE`

What I want to do is to delete

`$weights :List of 1024 ..$ : num [1:8] 0.1283 0.1336 0.1026 0.0927 0.071 ...` if `test1=FALSE`.

I am trying the following code but it dosent work.

```
for (i in 1:1024){   
ifelse(test1[[i]]==FALSE,
       datlistw.id2$weights[i]=NULL,
       datlistw.id2$weights[i]=datlistw.id2$weights[i])
}
```

This does not work. Does anybody has a suggestion?

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datlistw.id2$weights <- datlistw.id2$weights[test1]
```

will do the trick.

Comment: I got the following error:

Error in datlistw.id2$weights[[test1]] : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2